# What is the word for a person who is better than me but jealous of my mere achievements?

Tags: single-word-requests

There's this girl who is wayyyy better than me but keep on commenting on the little things I get more than her and tries to pull me down using those chances which is so irritating...

Comment: It depends - Centaurus' answer (*envious*) is, of course, correct. However, there may be other issues at play, such as *insecurity*. Psychology is off-topic on this forum, but if you edit your question to provide more information about *what aspect* of jealousy you are trying to highlight, you may get an answer that more fully matches what you have in mind.

Comment: Since I'm a college student maybe academic wise or even future plans...jobs n performance... opportunities...pressure from parents

Comment: Can we simply say "asshole"?  I'm not sure if one can get more technical in this situation.

Comment: Asshole is too good for her haha...but thanks max that helped a lot

Comment: If [those](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/339141/what-is-the-word-for-a-person-who-is-better-than-me-but-jealous-of-my-mere-achie?noredirect=1#comment780657_339141) are the points of contention, then *envious* (or your own word *jealous*) fits the bill.

Comment: Well she called me a Rodomontadist

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Writing advice requests are out of scope.
Questions that invite many equally valid answers are out of scope.
Word or phrase requests are out of scope, unless they are expert-level, particularly interesting, unique, and thought-provoking, and show effort and research.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That person is **envious**

Someone who regards you in an envious way is not necessarily a worse person.  They can be highly qualified in several ways, and still be envious.

**[envious](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/envious)**: feeling, expressing, or characterized by envy.

**[envy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/envy)**: a feeling of discontent and resentment aroused by and in conjunction with desire for the possessions or qualities of another.

ps - "way better than me"?  Academically, I presume.

Comment: Omg u guys can just read my mind!! Yeah I'm not competitive but people just spies on me whether I'm sleeping or studying which is way too irritating for me... just gimme a break man don't involve me in your introverted life